# Comment system for Node.js?

Tags: open-source, cms, node.js

I am searching for a simple Node.js **CMS** which provides a **sign up** and/or **commenting** system for users.

[Keystone](http://keystonejs.com/) goes in that direction, however it does not provide user sign ups nor commenting.

Comment: Do you care about licensing/pricing?

Comment: yes. It should be MIT or any other truely free license.

Comment: A quick Google search shows up [Calipso](http://calip.so/). Have you tried?